# Umbraco 6 and building a one page site?

Tags: umbraco

For some time now I've been interested in building a one page site that loads all the content via ajax (allowing me to do fancy transitions between pages). I've been looking at this example here: http://hashbang.envoyat.com/the-umbraco-approach/

But I wonder whether anyone has achieved the same thing using Umbraco 6 or even 4.10 ie. any version using MVC.

Are there any tutorials for doing this in v6? Has anyone managed to successfully do this?

I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a singlepage website with umbraco 6 and MVC. It does not differ that much from a normal website. 
I created a normal content tree and a separate view for every functional part of the website. 
Just render al your functionalities at once and use HTML and JavaScript to navigate.
Maybe you can use some lazy loading of you have a large website

Comment: Thanks Martijn, but did you manage to use hashbanging successfully, so search engines could index your site?

Comment: Yes we did, we used a combination of Urlrewrite and jQuery to prevent using hashes, which resulted in "normal" urls.
Unfortunately it was a proof of concept website that has never gone live.